# Summation distributive definition

Tags: summation

Suppose I have the following definition:
$$\sum_{k=0}^N m_k\zeta^{1-k},$$

where $m_k$ is an integer and $\zeta$ is a complex number $\zeta=e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i\sin\theta$ with $\theta = 0\cdots2\pi$. This can also be expanded as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^N m_k\zeta^{1-k}=\sum_{k=0}^N m_k\zeta\zeta^{-k}.$$

But, why is it *not* correct to write

$$\sum_{k=0}^N m_k\zeta^{1-k}=\sum_{k=0}^N m_k\zeta + \sum_{k=0}^N m_k\zeta^{-k}?$$

My calculation suggests that the *real* part of latter always gives me twice as the first two.

Can anyone explain?